# Ordenar items de un option en forma Descendente

Tags: javascript, html

Como puedo hacer para que los `options` estén ordenados de forma descendentes es decir que empiecen desde 2019, 2018, 2017...

```js
//Creacion de los selectores año
var selectAnioDesde = document.getElementById('anio_desde');

for (var i = 1900; i < 2020; i++) {
    var optAnioDesde = document.createElement('option');
    optAnioDesde.value = i ;
    optAnioDesde.innerHTML = i;
    selectAnioDesde.appendChild(optAnioDesde);
}

var selectAnioHasta = document.getElementById('anio_hasta');

for (var i = 1900; i < 2020; i++) {
    var optAnioHasta = document.createElement('option');
    optAnioHasta.value = i ;
    optAnioHasta.innerHTML = i;
    selectAnioHasta.appendChild(optAnioHasta);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <select name="anio_desde" id="anio_desde">
        <option value="0">Desde</option>
    </select>
    <select name="anio_desde" id="anio_hasta">
        <option value="0">Hasta</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Puedes hacerlo iniciando tu variable desde el maximo e irlo reduciondo hasta el valor que desees.

```js
//Creacion de los selectores año
var selectAnioDesde = document.getElementById('anio_desde');

for (var i = 2019; i >= 1900; i--) {
    var optAnioDesde = document.createElement('option');
    optAnioDesde.value = i ;
    optAnioDesde.innerHTML = i;
    selectAnioDesde.appendChild(optAnioDesde);
}

var selectAnioHasta = document.getElementById('anio_hasta');

for (var i = 2019; i >= 1900; i--) {
    var optAnioHasta = document.createElement('option');
    optAnioHasta.value = i ;
    optAnioHasta.innerHTML = i;
    selectAnioHasta.appendChild(optAnioHasta);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <select name="anio_desde" id="anio_desde">
        <option value="0">Desde</option>
    </select>
    <select name="anio_desde" id="anio_hasta">
        <option value="0">Hasta</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```